# Is it possible to get notifications on lock screen on ubuntu unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, screen, lock-screen

As we already know on Gnome lock screen we get notifications such as pidgin chat notifications etc.

Same like Gnome, is there any command, configuration or software we need to change to get notifications on lock screen?

Comment: i think Gnome is the one by which we can able to get notification.

Comment: I am fan of Unity! It will be great if I get notification on unit lock screen.